# Search and Replace in Sublime 3

Tags: sublimetext3

I've been googling like a madman, but for the life of me I can't figure out how to do these 2 things in Sublime Text 3:

- Replace *all occurrences* of a string in the file tree, *immediately*.
- Interactively *replace or skip* occurrences of a string in the file tree.

All I can manage to do is list and navigate the found matches. After that, I have to look at each file, manually alter the code and save.

Answer (score 1):

**In single file**

*Replace all occurrences of a string in the file tree, immediately.*

Hit  <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>, the prompt will open in the bottom of the window, the text of the button are self explanatory

*Interactively replace or skip occurrences of a string in the file tree.*

Hit  <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>, the prompt will open in the bottom of the window, if you want to replace only this occurrence then click on `Replace`, if not then click `Find`, then will select only next occurrence of the search string and then click `Replace`. This way you can customize search and replace.

**In entire directory or folder**

*Replace all occurrences of a string in the file tree, immediately.*

Hit  <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>, the prompt will open in the bottom of the window. There is a `Replace` button in the bottom right.

*Interactively replace or skip occurrences of a string in the file tree.*

Hit  <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>, the prompt will open in the bottom of the window, Hit `Find`, then manually double click on the text (that you want to replace) shown in result (tab title `Find Results`) , that file will get open and replace there. In this way you can customize your custom find and replace in entire directory.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer. I tried your suggestions, but I still have to manually edit and/or save each file

Comment: @slezica In the `Ctrl+Shift+F` panel, there's a button in the bottom right to that says "Replace".